# How do I force ext3 partition to the "error" state?

Tags: testing, ext3

I have a script where fsck is called in case filesystem is in "error" state only.
I'd like to tests it.
Unfortunatelly I don't know how to force "error" state on ext3 partition.

The only one idea I have is run fsck on mounted partition first. AS soon as there is warning that filesystem can be damaged, I expect it can help. Need to try.
Meanwhile, may be anyone knows answer already?

Answer (score 10):

Well, here it is:
debugfs -w -R "ssv state 2" /dev/sda1

debugfs is part of e2fsprogs package intended for low level access to ext2/3 filesystems.

```
-w - work in r/w;
-R - run one command and exit;
ssv - set superblock value, self-describing;
state - just a name of the field containing state of filesystem.
```

Codes are:

```
0 - not clean
1 - clean
2 - not clean with errors
```

Answer (score 4):

I fiddled with this briefly in a VM. My initial thought was to nuke the partition's primary superblock. Doing so does not cause dumpe2fs to report a "filesystem state" of "error" but it does (obviously) break your partition ("Bad magic number in super-block") ... so maybe that's all you need for your testing. Running fsck against a partition in this state and inspecting the value of `$?` will report a status of 8 (operational error).

Anyway, this is dangerous and I would not advise doing it on any system where you have data you care about. Try it in a VM like I did.

You can get some information about the file system like this:

```
dumpe2fs /dev/sda1 | egrep "state|superblock|Block size"
```

You will see that the filesystem has a primary superblock, and some number of backup superblocks. If you are prepared to break things, take note of a few things in that output:

- "Block size: X": take note of X
- "Primary superblock at Y": take note Y
- "Backup superblock at Z": take note of at least one Z

Now destroy your primary superblock:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda1 bs=X count=1 seek=Y
```

Congratulations! Your filesystem is now broken.

Unmount it if it is mounted:

```
umount /dev/sda1
```

Then run fsck specifying the location of one of the backup superblocks noted earlier:

```
fsck -b Z /dev/sda1
```

Now mount /dev/sda1 somewhere, and you should be back in business.

Comment: Thank You for investigation.
Actually I need "error" state because my script use dumpe2fs.
Presence of real damage to filesystem doesn't matter, only state matters.